# What is the property of being right versus left called?

Tags: single-word-requests

One could use "direction" to describe this property, but it is too wide, and I would like to find a term that narrows it down further, to describe the property (of a direction) of being either to the left or to the right. So, you could say for example that the xx of the object yy is left, where xx is the name of the property. Or you could say, "the xx of parts of the brain determines whether they're dealing more with logical thinking, or more with artistic creativity".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126263/discussion-on-question-by-alpha-pi-what-is-the-property-of-being-right-versus-le).

Answer (score 2):

*handed*

Gloves and scissors are handed - make sure you get the correct orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider something simple like "side".

> the side of parts of the brain determines whether they're dealing more with logical thinking, or more with artistic creativity? (Right for the former, left for the latter.)

> the side of the object yy is left

Which is a bit of an awkward sentence, perhaps reworded as:

> Object yy is the left side of object zz.